# Can I access picture library from a background agent on WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

As the title said, is there have way to read pictures from a background agent? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pictures library from background agent. The complete list of unsupported APIs in background agent can be found here: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.